# Why does this error occur? How can I upload file at jsp?

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to make a shopping mall project, but I've never dealt with Jsp, so I'm not good at it. There was an error creating the product registration page.

[DB Info]

```
create table product_kly (
    peq int primary key,
    pname varchar2(40) not null,
    nick varchar2(30) not null,
    price int not null,
    area varchar2(20) not null,
    content varchar2(2000) not null,
    pimage varchar2(500)
);
```

[form Jsp]

```
<form action="product_addCtrl.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="nick" value="<%=nick %>">
    product name
    <input type="text" name="pname">
    sell area
    <input type="text" name="area">
    price
    <input type="number" name="price">
    Content
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="pimage">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

[product_addCtrl.jsp]

```
<%
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    String nick = request.getParameter("nick");
    String pname = request.getParameter("pname");
    String area = request.getParameter("area");
    String price = request.getParameter("price");
    String content = request.getParameter("content");
    String pimage = request.getParameter("pimage");
    try {
        File image = new File(pimage);
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into product_kly (peq, pname, nick, price, area, content, pimage) " + "values((select nvl(max(peq), 0)+1 from product_kly), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        stmt.setString(1, pname);
        stmt.setString(2, nick);
        stmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(price));
        stmt.setString(4, area);
        stmt.setString(5, content);
        fis = new FileInputStream(image);
        stmt.setBinaryStream(6, (InputStream) fis, (int) (image.length()));
        int count = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
%>
```

Results of input and execution
No errors found but not inserted into the table.

Please Help me, geniuses! X(

Comment: What error occur ?

Comment: The error log was not found but was not entered into DB.

Comment: Your `pimage` column is `varchar` and you are using  `setBinaryStream` to set its value why ?

Comment: oh, when i before used blob  just same error occurred.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet